# Slicing poincare section

Tags: plotting

Let

```
H[q1p1_, q2_, p2_, q3_, p3_] = 
 0.9816 q1p1 + 1.1822 I q2 p2 + 1.2514 I q3 p3 - 0.0889594 I p2^3 - 
  0.0970894 I p2 p3^2 - 0.219332 p1q1 q2 + 0.256743 I p2^2 q2 - 
  0.0970894 I p3^2 q2 + 0.0256743 I p2 q2^2 - 0.0889594 I q2^3 - 
  0.194179 p2 p3 q3 - 0.194179 p3 q2 q3 + 0.0970894 I p2 q3^2 + 
  0.0970894 I q2 q3^2
```

This Hamiltonian systems has a first integral $I_{1}=q_{1}p_{1}$ which I set as $0$ so that I get $H(0,\bar{q},\bar{p})$ where $\bar{q}=(q_{2},q_{3})$ and $\bar{p}=(p_{2},p_{3})$. Now I want to compute the poincare section $q_{3}=0$ such that 
$H(0,\bar{q},\bar{p})=0.4$.

If it's correct I should get plots of these forms

[image: Centre manifold]

Could someone help me out?

---

I will give the mathematical background to get a clear image of my problem.

Assume the following Hamiltonian system where $r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}$

\begin{equation}
H = \dfrac{1}{2}(P^{2}_{x}+P^{2}_{y}+P^{2}_{z})+yP_{x}-xP_{y}-\dfrac{1}{2}(2x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2})-\dfrac{1}{r}
-a_{x}x-a_{y}y-a_{z}z
\end{equation}

Now I want to split the centre manifold from the hyperbolic on. To do this we first need to make a power expansion of $H$

\begin{equation}
H=\sum_{n\geq 2}H_{n}
\end{equation}

First i find the equilibrium

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} \dfrac{\partial{H}}{\partial{P_{x}}} &= P_{x} + y \\ \dfrac{\partial{H}}{\partial{P_{y}}} &= P_{y} - x \\
 \dfrac{\partial{H}}{\partial{P_{z}}} &= P_{z}\\ 
 \dfrac{\partial{H}}{\partial{y}} &= P_{x} + y + \dfrac{y}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3}} \\ 
 \dfrac{\partial{H}}{\partial{x}} &= -P_{y} - 2x + \dfrac{x}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3}} - a_{x}\\ \dfrac{\partial{H}}{\partial{z}} &= z + \dfrac{z}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3}} \end{aligned}\end{equation}

One finds that $ P_{x}=P_{z}=z=y=0$

Now to find the equilibrium and $H_{2}$ I used the following code.

```
H=1/2(px^2+py^2+pz^2)+ypx-xpy-1/2(2x^2_y^2-z^2)-1Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]
FullSimplify[Nsolve[x^3-4.625x+1=0,x]]
```

I get 3 equilibrium where I use $xs=1.36$ as he solution of the function.
Then to find $H_{2}$

```
Expand[simplify[Normal[Series[H/.{x->xs+X,py->ps+Py},{X,0,2},{y,0,2},
{z,0,2},{px,0,2},{Py,0,2},{pz,0,2}]],xs>0]]
```

Cancelling out the higher and lower order terms I get:

\begin{equation}
H_{2}(q,p) = \dfrac{P_{x}^{2}}{2} +\dfrac{P_{y}^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{P_{z}^{2}}{2}-P_{y}-x^{2}-\dfrac{x^{2}}{x_{s}^{3}}-x_{s}^{2}+P_{x}y +\dfrac{y^{2}}{2} + \dfrac{y^{2}}{2x_{s}^{2}}+\dfrac{z^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{z^{2}}{2x_{s}^{3}}
\end{equation}

Now computing the hessian

```
H2 = 1/2(px^2+Py^2+pz^2+y^2+z^2)+pxy-xPy+1/2xs^3(z^2+y^2)
/.{Py->py,X->x} 
L={
Table[D[D[H2,px],u],{u,{x,y,z,px,py,pz}}],
Table[D[D[H2,py],u],{u,{x,y,z,px,py,pz}}],
Table[D[D[H2,pz],u],{u,{x,y,z,px,py,pz}}],
Table[D[-D[H2,x],u],{u,{x,y,z,px,py,pz}}],
Table[D[-D[H2,y],u],{u,{x,y,z,px,py,pz}}],
Table[D[-D[H2,z],u],{u,{x,y,z,px,py,pz}}],
```

Computing eigenvalues

```
FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[L]/.xs->1.36`]
```

Now to continue with the symplectic transformation I write $w=\sqrt{1+1/xs^{3}}$ and $\bold{H}_{2}(x,y)$ in the following way (In this section the coordinates are slightly changed 
$ (x,P_{x},y,P_{y},z,P_{z})=(x_{1},y_{1},x_{2},y_{2},z_{1},z_{2})$)

```
% Define the second order Hamiltonian
H2=1/2(y1^2+y2^2)-w^2x1^2+1/2(w^2x2^2)-x1y2+x2y1+1/2(y3^2+w^2x3^2);
wval=w->(Sqrt[1+1/xs^3]/.xs->N[136/100,16])
%%Neglecting the z,pz terms will give an easier computation 
h2m = (H2/.{x3 ->0,y3-> 0})
```

\begin{equation}
   \bold{H}_{2} -w^{2}x^{2}+\dfrac{w^{2}y^{2}}{2}yP_{x}-xP_{y}+\dfrac{P_{x}^{2}+P_{y}^{2}}{2}
\end{equation}

Now computing the vector field for $\bold{H_{2}}$ yields the following matrix:
\begin{equation*}
\bold{X}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1&1&0\\
2w^{2} & 0&0 &1\\
 -1 & 0&0 &1\\
  0& -1&-w^{2}&0
   \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

The eigenvectors of $\bold{X}$ should be symplectic in order to reduce the system to a centre manifold. In this case however it is not symplectic until it is scaled. First let $D$ be the following matrix:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&-1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
To check whether it is symplectic or not the following equality should hold where $Q$ is the matrix containing the eigenvectors.
\begin{equation*}
QDQ^{T}=D
\end{equation*}

```
% Define poisson brackets in mathematica
pb4[F_,G_] :=
D[F,x1]D[G,y1]-D[F,y1]D[G,x1]+D[F,x2]D[G,y2]-D[F,y2]D[G,x2]
%
% Define the vector field
vf[H_,vars_]:=Table[D[pb4[u,H],v],{u,vars},{v,vars}]
%
% Define again the Hessian
AA=vf[H2m,{x1,y1,x2,y2}]
%
% Computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors
Chop[Eigenvalues[AA/.wval]]
evAA=Chop[Eigenvectors[AA/.wval]]
%
% Checking whether the transformation is symplectic
JJ4={{0,1,0,0},{-1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,-1,0}};
%
% The transformation matrix is not symplectic so one has to 
% define a scaled version
fJJ = Chop[evAA.JJ4.transpose[evAA]]))//MatrixForm
%
% Scaled version 
tm = {
1/Sqrt[fJJ[[1,2]]]evAA[[1]],
1/Sqrt[-fJJ[[2,1]]]evAA[[2]],
1/Sqrt[fJJ[[3,4]]]evAA[[3]],
1/Sqrt[-fJJ[[4,3]]]evAA[[4]],
Chop[tm.JJ4.Transpose[tm]]
ttm=Transpose[tm]/;
%
% Defining the transformation for x3,y3
r3={x3->u3/Sqrt[w],y3->Sqrt[w]v3}/.
{u3->(q3+ip3)/Sqrt[2],v3->(p3+Iq3)/Sqrt[2]}
%
% Transformation matrix is
tm3 = {{D[x3/.r3,q3],D[x3/.r3,p3]},{D[y3/.r3,q3],D[y3/.r3,p3]}}
%
% Total canonical transformation 
trule = Join[Mapthread[Rule,{{x1,y1,x2,y2},ttm.{q1,p1,q2,p2}}],
r3/.wval]
%
% Expressing H2 in the new variables
Chop[Expand[H2/.wval/.trule]]
%
```

Making a third degree expansion

```
Expand[simplify[Normal[Series[H/.{x->xs+X,py->ps+Py},{X,0,3},{y,0,3},
{z,0,3},{px,0,3},{Py,0,3},{pz,0,3}]],xs>0]]
%cancelling out higher and lower order terms
H3= x1^3/(xs^4)-3x1 x2^2/(2xs^4)-3x1 x3^2/(2xs^4)
Expressing H3 in the new variables
H3M = Chop[Expand[H3/.wval/.trule]]
H3m = (H3M /. {xs -> 1.36})
```

Now with this transformation $H_{2}$ and $H_{3}$ can be expressed as follows

\begin{equation}
H_{2}(q,p) = \lambda q_{1}p_{1} +i\omega_{1}q_{2}p_{2}+i\omega_{2}q_{3}p_{3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
H_{3}(q,p) = h_{1}p_{1}^{3} + h_{2}p_{1}^{2}p_{2} +h_{3}p_{1}p_{2}^{2}+ h_{4}p_{2}^{3}+h_{5}p_{1}p_{3}^{2}\\+h_{6}p_{2}p_{3}^{2}+ h_{7}p_{1}^{2}q_{1}+ h_{8}p_{1}p_{2}q_{1} + h_{9}p_{2}^{2}q_{1}+h_{10}p_{3}^{2}q_{1}\\+h_{11}p_{1}q_{1}^{2}+h_{12}p_{2}q_{1}^{2} +h_{13}q_{1}^{3}+h_{14}p_{1}^{2}q_{2} +h_{15}p_{1}p_{2}q_{2}\\+h_{16}p_{2}^{2}q_{2}+h_{17}p_{3}^{2}q_{2}+h_{18}p_{1}q_{1}q_{2}+h_{19}p_{2}q_{1}q_{2}+h_{20}q_{1}^{2}q_{2}\\+h_{21}p_{1}q_{2}^{2}+h_{22}p_{2}q_{2}^{2}+h_{23}q_{1}q_{2}^{2}+h_{24}q_{2}^{3}+h_{25}p_{1}p_{3}q_{3}\\+h_{26}p_{2}p_{3}q_{3}+h_{27}p_{3}q_{1}q_{3}+h_{28}p_{3}q_{2}q_{3}+h_{29}p_{1}q_{3}^{2}+h_{30}p_{2}q{3}^{2}+\\h_{31}q_{1}q{3}^{2}+h_{32}q_{2}q_{3}^{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
Where $h_{i}$ for $i = 1,2,3, \dots,32$ are constants

Because the central directions needs to be uncoupled from the hyperbolic ones, it not interesting to compute the complete normal form. To have a great radius of convergence it is necessary to stay close to the original form, thus the number of elimination of the monomials should stay low In order to do so the first component of the integer vector $k_{q}$ cannot be equal to the first component of the integer vector $k_{p}$. So $H_{3}(q,p)$ can be written as follows:

\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\hat{H}_{3}(q,p) = h_{4}p_{2}^{2}+h_{6}p_{2}p_{3}^{2}+h_{8}p_{1}p_{2}q_{1}+h_{16}p_{2}^{2}q_{2}\\+h_{17}p_{3}^{2}q_{2}+h_{18}p_{1}q_{1}q_{2}+h_{22}p_{2}q_{2}^{2}+h_{24}q_{2}^{3}+h_{26}p_{2}p_{3}q_{3}+h_{28}p_{3}q_{2}q_{3}+h_{30}p_{2}q_{3}^{2}\\+h_{32}q_{2}q_{3}^{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}

Now because $n \geq 3$ the transformed Hamiltonian can be expressed as follows.

\begin{equation}
\hat{H}(q,p) = H_{2}(q,p) + \hat{H}_{3}(q,p)+ \hat{H}_{4}(q,p)+ ,\dots ,+\hat{H}_{N}(q,p)
\end{equation}

Because the nomonial $q^{k_{p}}p^{k_{p}}$ is eliminated such that the first factor of $k_{p}$ is different from $k_{q}$ the homogeneous polynomial $\hat{H}_{3}$ is depended on $q_{1}p_{1}$

\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_{3}(q,p) = \hat{H}_{3}(q_{1}p_{1},q_{2},p_{2},q_{3},p_{3}) 
\end{equation}
This same method can be done until a finite order $N$ where $\hat{H}_{N}$ depends on $q_{1}p_{1}$ as well. Then an Hamiltonian system of the following form can be seen.

\begin{equation}
\bar{H}(q,p) = \bar{H}_{N}(q,p) + R_{N+1}(q,p)
\end{equation}
Where $R_{N+1}$ is called the remainder of order $N+1$. The reminder can be dropped because it is neglectable near the origin. Next using $I_{1}=q_{1}p_{1}$, $\bar{q}=(q_{2},q_{3})$ and $\bar{p}=(p_{2},p_{3})$ and setting $I_{1}=0$ one restricts the Hamiltonian system to an invariant model which is tangent to the equilibrium. So get $\bar{H}_{N}(0,\bar{q},\bar{p})$.

Now my final question, I want to plot $\bar{H}_{3}(0,\bar{q},\bar{p})=0.4$ in $(q_{2},p_{2})$ coordinates for $q_{3}=0$.
But as I see it my $\bar{H}_{3}(0,\bar{q},\bar{p})$ is equal to the following which is imaginary, is this correct?

```
H[q1p1_, q2_, p2_, q3_, p3_] = 
0.9816 q1p1 + 1.1822 I q2 p2 + 1.2514 I q3 p3 - 0.0889594 I p2^3 - 
0.0970894 I p2 p3^2 - 0.219332 p1q1 q2 + 0.256743 I p2^2 q2 - 
0.0970894 I p3^2 q2 + 0.0256743 I p2 q2^2 - 0.0889594 I q2^3 - 
0.194179 p2 p3 q3 - 0.194179 p3 q2 q3 + 0.0970894 I p2 q3^2 + 
0.0970894 I q2 q3^2
```

If its correct I should get something like this picture
[image]

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking? What is the problem?

Comment: I want to compute the given poincare section where 0.4 is the initial data for the flow of the Hamiltonian $H$. If it's correct I should get intersections of the orbit with $q_{3}=0$ which should look like the graphs I gave.

Comment: A broader range of people might be able to help you out if you give more mathematical details that don't assume knowledge of the physics of your system.

Comment: You might be interested in [Poincaré Sections](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/poincare-sections.html) documentation.

Comment: @Tigran You "answer" was really an extended explanation of your question, right? I append it as an edit to your question. You can always edit your question own question. On the left side next to your username _under_ your question, you find little gray links where "edit" is one of them.